# ¿Cómo mostrar un PDF desde mi BD?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Quiero saber como mostrar un archivo pdf de mi base de datos este es el codigo

```
<?php
    


  
        session_start();

      require 'conexion.php';
   
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("Location:login.php");
            
        
        
    }else{
        
        $id_user=$_SESSION["id_usuario"];
            $sql="select * from masterc2_boletas.sg_boleta a
    join sg_usuario b
    on a.id_user=b.id_user
    join sg_admin g
    on a.id_admin=g.id_admin where a.id_user='$id_user'";
        }
    $where="";
    
    
    
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
    
    
?>



<html lang="es">
    
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mitabla').DataTable({
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "language":{
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "processing":     "Procesando...",
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
                "paginate": {
                    "next":       "Siguiente",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },                  
            }
            
        }); 
    }); 
        </script>
        
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Registro de Prospeccion</h2>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <h4 style="text-align:left">Num. Prospeccion</h4>
                <div>
                    <th>Izi Jr</th>
                    <?php  echo $row1["suma1"]; ?> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <th>Izi Smart</th>
                    <?php  echo $row3["suma3"]; ?> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <th>Android Mini</th>
                    <?php  echo $row2["suma2"]; ?> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <th>Android Max</th>
                    <?php  echo $row4["suma4"]; ?> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <th>Izi App</th>
                    <?php  echo $row6["suma6"]; ?> 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <th>Izi Online</th>
                    <?php  echo $row5["suma5"]; ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
            
                <a href="cierre.php" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:right;">Cerrar sesion</a>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="nuevo.php" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo Registro</a>
            </div>
            
            <br>
            
            <div class="row table-responsive">
                <table class="display" id="mitabla">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id Boleta</th>
                            <th>Id usuario</th>
                            <th>Fecha Boleta</th>
                            <th>Pdf</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido</th>
                            <th>Cargo</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                         
                        <td><?php echo $row['id_boleta']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['id_user']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['fecha_boleta'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['pdf_boleta'];  ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['nom_usuario']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ape_usuario']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['cargo_usuario']; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="modificar.php?id_prueba=<?php echo $row['id_prueba']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" data-href="eliminar.php?id_prueba=<?php echo $row['id_prueba']; ?>"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <?php } ?>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Eliminar Registro</h4>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Desea eliminar <?php echo $row['id_user']; ?> este registro?
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
                
                $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
            });
        </script>   
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Te faltó indicar cuál es el problema con el código que nos muestras. Dónde está el PDF que mencionas y qué falla cuando intentas mostrarlo? Qué debería pasar y qué pasa en su lugar?

Comment: Por cierto, puedes [edit] y añadir las aclaraciones que hacen falta. Evita usar el campo de respuesta para añadir info

Comment: ¿Usas alguna herramienta en específico para crear el PDF? ¿Si pones un `var_dump($row);` dentro del `while` qué muestra?

Comment: me sale error  **while(var_dump($row) = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));**